# Validate a specific value with jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to validate my form to check a field for a specific value. If a user types a value more than 5 (`>= 5`) into a textbox, validation should return an error. How can I do this with jQuery validation?

```
    <input type='text' name='qty' value='must lower than 5'/>
```

Comment: are you using validation plugins ??

Comment: use `keyup` or `keydown` events of jquery

Comment: yes.. i used jquery validation 1.11

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

you might want to change your `value=''` to `placeholder=''`

```
<input type='text' name='qty' id='txt_qty' placeholder='must be lower than 5'>
```

here is the script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#txt_qty').keyup(function()
        {
             var qty = $(this).val();
            if(qty > 5)
            {
                alert('Quantity must not be more than 5');
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });
     });   
</script>
```

Its just simple but I hope this helps.

Comment: user will enter the value after page loads u have not used any event to check the value

Comment: how if i have more than one input text

Comment: @dianuj sorry, was a little bit excited.

Comment: you can assign same class to all input and in `$(this)` u will get the value of that text input

Comment: @casper what do you mean? can you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#formID").submit(function(){
        var qty = $('#txt_qty').val();
        if(qty > 5)
        {
           alert('Quantity must not be more than 5');
           $('#txt_qty').val('');
           return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use more.. use classes and loop them

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#formID").submit(function(){
        var ret= true;
        $(".checkthis").each(function(){
            var qty = $(this).val();
            if(qty > 5){
              alert('Quantity must not be more than 5');
              $(this).val('');
              ret = false;
            }
        });
        return ret;
    });
});
</script>
```